# Locking the insertion of DB records to happen only once

Tags: c#, locking, mutex

I'm new to C# and have a this problem:

I have an `.aspx` page that accepts a parameter `eventId`.

On the first time this page is requested with a specific `eventId`, I need to insert some rows into the database that are unique to that event.

All other times that the page is requested with that `eventId`, no rows should be inserted.

I can query the database to see if those rows already exist for that event, but this will not prevent issues of concurrency.

Say, 2 clients requested that page with `eventId = 7` exactly at the same time - rows for that event might be inserted twice.

How can I use a Mutex/Lock/Monitor or anything else to avoid that?

I need the locking mechanism to be identified by a string - the event id

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You say below you insert 30 records? How do you do this? One at a time? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your db create a unique index based on event id. on your asp page always insert and handle the case where the insert fails. if the insert fails the event id has already been used by someone else. in this design the db does the synchronization.

Comment: That's not good for me cause I insert around 30 records for each event to a single table. so the event id cannot be used as an index

Comment: create a new table with just the event id as column plus unique index.

Answer (score 0):

The "read if the event id is already there" and "insert that event id" method should run in transactions. 
If you use a TransactionScope, you can set the isolation level to Serializable, that will ensure you can never have concurrent access at database level so you can prevent inserting twice the event.

However, I would also add a unique key index on that field in the database, like opi suggests.